# Remote disk usage analyzer over SSH from OS X?

Tags: macos, ssh, disk-space

On Ubuntu, I enjoyed the disk usage analyzer "Baobab" to drill down into my file system and see what was taking up so much space. One invaluable feature was to connect to a remote system over SSH and display the nice pie charts of that system.

Now that I'm stuck on a Mac, that specific tool isn't easily* available. Is there an alternative for displaying a multilevel pie chart of a remote file system over SSH for OS X?

- Baobab is available through MacPorts as part of the gnome-utils package, but it carries with it the entire gnome-desktop suite as a dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I can use Macfusion to mount a remote file system over SSH so it appears to be local. Then I can use one of the many [alternatives to Baobab](http://alternativeto.net/desktop/baobab/?platform=mac) that don't have this feature.

Answer (score 2):

You don't necessarily need to install the utility on your Mac for that purpose.
[NCDU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncdu) is a disk analyzer based on `ncurses` library and it offers a terminal-based UI.
You can also install it on your Mac via `homebrew`.

Answer (score 0):

What about running Baobab on the remote server using your Mac as the X server?

I'm not familiar with Baobab, but this test will demonstrate what I mean:

```
(localhost) $ ssh -X remote-host

(remote-host) $ xclock &
```

This should launch xclock on your Mac's display. If that works, try launching Baobab from the command line and watch the pretty pictures on your mac.

This relies on X forwarding being enabled on both the client and server sides. Default configuration usually allows this, but some places lock that down.